# c# Soundplayer doesnt play full .wav file cuts right in it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Im trying to add a sound to my c# console app but the problem is that when the sound is supposed to start playing you can hear the sound starting but it cuts like right into it and the full sound is not finished. There is no errors with the file path because it points on the wav file. But weird thing is if i add a second PlaySync(), the first sound is cut... but the second plays the audio file in full.

Any guiddance how i could solve this? i want to be able to play the full audio at first.
Thank you

```
        public static void playSound()
        {
            string workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string projectDirectory = Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = projectDirectory + "/Sounds/9098__ddohler__typewriter.wav";
            player.PlaySync();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }





        public static void playSound()
        {
            string workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string projectDirectory = Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
            SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
            player.SoundLocation = projectDirectory + "/Sounds/9098__ddohler__typewriter.wav";
            player.PlaySync();
            player.PlaySync();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Try updating the drivers in your machine motherboad where the codec is located.  This doesn't look like a Net issue.   Net is using the windows dlls and the motherboard drives to play the file.

Comment: I will try this, thank you!

Comment: Updated my computer and now it works!!! Thank you so much!